# Node.js http request close response after eventEmitter callback

Tags: node.js, http, callback, es6-modules, eventemitter

I have a node.js ES6 project running on a Raspberry Pi with a main file and some imported ES6 child modules (http and a temperature sensor in the example).

When the server receives a request I would want to call an async parent function (I can do this with EventEmitter) and on callback print temperature value on the page.

Am I allowed to do this? 
The problem is that response is not closed (so client page never finish) and if I repeat the call it tells me that the server :port is already busy.

**Short summary**

```
...
self.webserver.on('request', async (req, res) => {
  ...
  self.emit('remoteCall', path, JSON.stringify(queryData)); // call parent
  self.on('callback',(data)=>{ // <-- HERE callback from index.js with temperature data collected
   res.write(data);
   res.end(); // <-- I want to wait for temperature data and then end server response
  });
});
...
```

**Full example**

```
/**
 * ./app/services/server/server.js Server module
 */
const http = require('http');
const url = require('url');
const EventEmitter = require( 'events' );

class Server extends EventEmitter {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.webserver = http.createServer();
    this.remoteServer = 'https://example.com/';
  }
  startServer(){
    const self = this;
    self.webserver.on('request', async (req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      const q = url.parse(req.url, true);
      if (q.pathname === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
        res.end();
        return;
      }
      const path = q.pathname;
      const queryData = q.query;
      res.write(path);
      res.write(JSON.stringify(queryData));

      self.emit('remoteCall', path, JSON.stringify(queryData)); // <-- send to index.js so it can execute temperature read
      self.on('callback',(data)=>{ // <-- HERE callback from index.js with temperature data collected
        console.log(data);
        res.write(data);
        res.end(); // <-- I want to wait for temperature data and then end server response
      }); 
    });
  }
  listen(){
    this.webserver.listen(8080);
    return
  }
}
export default Server;
```

```
/**
 * ./app/probes/tempereture/tempereture.js Temperature module
 */
const sensor = require('ds18x20');

class Temperature {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  async getTemperature() {
    const self = this;
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      sensor.get(self.id, function (err, tempObj) {
        if (err) { throw err; }
        resolve({id: self.id, value: tempObj});
      });
    });
  }
}
export default Temperature;
```

```
/**
 * ./app/evoirement/pot/pot.js Temperature object parent
 */
import Temperature from '../../probes/temperature/temperature';

class Pot {
  constructor({potID, waterTemperatureProbeID}) {
    this.id = potID;
    this.waterTemperature = new Temperature(waterTemperatureProbeID);
  }
}
export default Pot;
```

```
/**
 * index.js Main file
 */

import Pot from './app/envoirement/pot/pot';
import Server from './app/services/server/server';

class Main {
  constructor(){
    this.server = new Server();
    this.appSetup();
  }
  appSetup(){
    const self = this;
    this.pot1 = new Pot({
      potID: 'pot1',
      waterTemperatureProbeID: '28-0114502296aa'
    });
    this.pot2 = new Pot({
      potID: 'pot2',
      waterTemperatureProbeID: '28-0114504ea1aa'
    });

    this.server.startServer();
    this.server.listen();
    this.server.on('remoteCall', (path, queryData) => { // <-- Received a request from http server
      console.log('remoteCall', path, queryData);
      self.pot1.waterTemperature.getTemperature().then(res=>{
        console.log(res);
        this.server.emit('callback', res)
      });
    });
  }
}
const app = new Main();
```

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't want to do this because the remote call is for the server - that means all concurrent connections. What you should be doing instead is make the remote call per request, not per server.

Just call `getTemperature()` directly in your request handler:

```
import Pot from './app/envoirement/pot/pot';

let pot1 = new Pot({
  potID: 'pot1',
  waterTemperatureProbeID: '28-0114502296aa'
});

class Server {
  constructor(){/* ... */}
  startServer(){
    const self = this;
    self.webserver.on('request', async (req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      const q = url.parse(req.url, true);
      if (q.pathname === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
        res.end();
        return;
      }
      const path = q.pathname;
      const queryData = q.query;
      res.write(path);
      res.write(JSON.stringify(queryData));

      pot1.waterTemperature.getTemperature().then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        res.write(data);
        res.end(); 
      }); 
    });
  }
  listen(){/* ... */}
}
```

If you don't want to hardcode `pot1` in Server then pass it as an argument to your constructor - a sort of lightweight dependency injection:

```
class Server {
  constructor(pot1){
      this.pot1 = pot1;

      // ...
  }
  startServer(){/* ... */}
  listen(){/* ... */}
}
```

If you want to factor out the sensors to make them more modular you can keep them in their own module:

```
// sensors.js
let pot1 = new Pot({
  potID: 'pot1',
  waterTemperatureProbeID: '28-0114502296aa'
});

let pot2 = new Pot({
  potID: 'pot2',
  waterTemperatureProbeID: '28-0114504ea1aa'
});

module.exports = {
  pots: [
    pot1,    // the namespacing of this API is really up to you
    pot2
  ]
}
```

Then you can import it in your Server:

```
let sensors = require('./sensors');

class Server {
  constructor(){/* ... */}
  startServer(){
    const self = this;
    self.webserver.on('request', async (req, res) => {
      res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
      const q = url.parse(req.url, true);
      if (q.pathname === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
        res.end();
        return;
      }
      const path = q.pathname;
      const queryData = q.query;
      res.write(path);
      res.write(JSON.stringify(queryData));

      sensors.pot[1].waterTemperature.getTemperature().then(data=>{
        console.log(data);
        res.write(data);
        res.end(); 
      }); 
    });
  }
  listen(){/* ... */}
}
```

Then you can query the sensors dynamically:

```
self.webserver.on('request', async (req, res) => {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  const q = url.parse(req.url, true);
  if (q.pathname === '/favicon.ico') {
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
    res.end();
    return;
  }
  const path = q.pathname;
  const queryData = q.query;
  const query = queryData.split('&').reduce(function(a,b){
    keyVal = b.split('=');
    a[keyVal[0]] = keyVal[1];
  },{});

  res.write(path);
  res.write(JSON.stringify(queryData));
  sensors.[query.type][query.idx].waterTemperature.getTemperature()
    .then(data=>{
      console.log(data);
      res.write(data);
      res.end(); 
    });
});
```

Now you can make requests like `http://server/get?type=pot&idx=0`. Again, if you don't want to hardcode importing the sensors in your Server file you can always pass it in as an argument to the constructor.

Comment: Really no way? I know I can reference the probe directly in the Server component and then call getTemperature() but I don't like this because I would want to avoid cross-reference between components.
Also, the full project will have more pots and sensors so I would need to put everything in the server object. I want to be able to send instructions like: 
**- pot1 - readTemperature,** 
**- pot2 - readTemperature,**
**- pot1 - readWaterLevel...**
So I think the best tidy solution would be to pass everything from server to external and when callback, print results on screen.

Comment: You can keep the pots in their own modules. I'll code a quick example